# Merge column and content of table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

***Merge column and content of table using javascript***

I have multiple columns in the below table. There are 3 columns in below scenario, which I want to merge and create a single column named `Development`

I want to Merge 3 columns : In Progress, Waiting for review, Fixed to only column with name 'Development' and also merge content of all 3 column to 1 column. How can I do it with javaScript or jquery ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered mytable" id="mytable">
        <thead class="sprint-board">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Product backlog items</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">New</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sprint_board">
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
              <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
            </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="sprint-board">
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">
                <div class="card" style="width: 10rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">width: 10rem;</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Progress</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Waiting for Review</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Fixed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">In Testing</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Resolved</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Closed</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sprint-board">Re-open</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: This seems to be static page. Can you please share the JSON data for the same, so that we can share the steps to merge the 3 column data into single column and after that rendering the data in table using javascript.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users